# FFmpeg skipping time after concat

Tags: video, merge, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate videos and in my resulting Videos I have the issue that at the concat edges my video is skipping/glitching.

---

### General Workflow

in general my workflow looks like this

1. Stream via ffmpeg
2. capture stream and segment all 2 mins in to TS files
3. concat TS file to MP4 video
4. cut MP4 video at the desired Timestamps

---

### Detailed Look at Step 4

as I am handling 2-hours+ videos I don't want to re-encode the whole video. So I am looking for the closest I Frames to my In and Outpoint and cut 1 Frame before/after. As my result I get 3 Videos (front/middle/back). Now it is only needed to re-encode front and back and concat all three Videos.
So far the theory

---

### General Observations

As I look at my resulting video, I obeservated the following.
frontpart duration is e.g. 3.2 secs. I skip framewise through the Video and get nice and clean timestamps ( 00:00:02.620, 00:00:02:660 )
As soon as I get to my cutting edge the timestamps are skipping some frames and changing  (00:00:03.200, 00:00:03.408 ,00:00:03.409). When I look only at the single frame images, their are no missing/dropped frames

when I concat my TS files, the results contains a messed up frame rate  e.g from constant 25 F/s to 25.0096 F/s

---

### FFMPEG instructions

FRONT Video

```
ffmpeg -ss 232.52 -i src.mp4 -t 3.24 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 31 -bf 0  -f mp4 -y front.mp4
ffmpeg version n3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libssh --enable-openssl
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'src.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 01:06:00.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 610 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], 537 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setpts (graph 0)
  setpts (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX LZCNT
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'front.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=   81 fps= 31 q=-1.0 Lsize=     151kB time=00:00:03.25 bitrate= 379.5kbits/s speed=1.23x
video:119kB audio:28kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.531915%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.43  size: 38268
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] frame P:80    Avg QP:21.05  size:  1038
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] mb I  I16..4: 71.4%  0.0% 28.6%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  7.8%  1.8%  0.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:89.6%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 21.8% 40.8% 23.1% inter: 1.6% 4.2% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] i16 v,h,dc,p: 66% 25%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 28% 15%  4%  4%  5%  4%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 24% 21%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] ref P L0: 74.3% 15.2% 10.5%
[libx264 @ 0x31ea160] kb/s:299.56
[aac @ 0x31edfa0] Qavg: 123.323
```

MIDDLE Video

```
ffmpeg -ss 235.88 -i src.mp4 -c copy -t 1492.96 -f mp4 -y middle.mp4 
ffmpeg version n3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libssh --enable-openssl
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'src.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 01:06:00.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 610 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], 537 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'middle.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], q=2-31, 537 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=37329 fps=16333 q=-1.0 Lsize=  113774kB time=00:24:52.95 bitrate= 624.3kbits/s speed= 653x
video:100359kB audio:12095kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.173957%
```

BACK Video

```
ffmpeg -ss 1728.88 -i 'src.mp4' -t 3.9199999999998 -filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 31 -bf 0  -f mp4 -y back.mp4
ffmpeg version n3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libssh --enable-openssl
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'src.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 01:06:00.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 610 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], 537 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setpts (graph 0)
  setpts (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX LZCNT
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'back.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=   98 fps= 27 q=-1.0 Lsize=     268kB time=00:00:03.92 bitrate= 559.2kbits/s speed=1.07x
video:230kB audio:33kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.538479%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] frame I:1     Avg QP:19.57  size:112129
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] frame P:97    Avg QP:21.68  size:  1270
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] mb I  I16..4: 35.4%  0.0% 64.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.1%  P16..4:  6.9%  2.0%  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:90.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 54.4% 69.1% 54.2% inter: 2.0% 3.6% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] i16 v,h,dc,p: 63% 23%  8%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 17% 11%  6%  8%  9%  7%  8%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 18% 24%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] ref P L0: 81.8% 11.5%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2672160] kb/s:480.15
[aac @ 0x2675fa0] Qavg: 119.994
```

CONCAT Videos

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -c copy -r 25 -y /concat.mp4 
ffmpeg version n3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libssh --enable-openssl
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, concat, from 'concat.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 74 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'concat.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x464 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:29], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 74 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=37508 fps=7256 q=-1.0 Lsize=  114285kB time=00:25:00.59 bitrate= 623.9kbits/s speed= 290x
video:100672kB audio:12598kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:1kB muxing overhead: 0.896435%
```

---

If needed I can provide samples.

Comment: Perhaps add `-vsync drop` to your last command? Samples would be good to have, of course.

Comment: I get the following error when using  `-vsync drop`

 `'Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument`


sample files will follow

Comment: here you can find my sample file [src.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByEkcmjJzDPcY3JXQ0gwRWVfbmM)

use the following FFMPEG commands
 FRONT

 `ffmpeg -ss 52.52 -i src.mp4 -t 3.04 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 -f mpegts -an  -y front.ts.ts`
MIDDLE
`ffmpeg -ss 55.64 -i src.mp4 -f mpegts -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -codec copy -t 293.96 -y middle.ts`
BACK
`ffmpeg -ss 349.76 -i src.mp4 -t 3.04 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 -f mpegts -an  -y back.ts`

Comment: CONCAT 

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc  -movflags +faststart -y result.mp4`